# array of functions which have different number of variables that need to pass in

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Lets say I have 3 objects with same method, except each objects calls different CardPopup.method in setTimeOut. Also, the fetch method in itemInfoHover1 passed in 2 variables,but passed in 3 variables in itemInfoHover2 and 3. And each showVisiblePopup have different variables too.
My questions is is there a way to optimized the 3 objects into one and call only the right one on click?
I am thinking maybe using array literals and $each, but I have no idea how to do it correctly.

```
    var itemInfoHover1 = {
           fetch : function(el, key){
        showFlag = true; 
        $(el).mouseout(function(){
            itemInfoHover1.hide();
        });
        clearTimeout(window.showtimeout);   
        window.showtimeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
            CardPopup.GetCardPopupNew(el.id, key, cardInfoHover.show);
        }, 100);
    },

    show: function (result) {
        showVisiblePopup(itemInfoHover1, 'itemDetails', result.source, result.contents, false);
    },
    hide: function () {
        hideVisiblePopup('itemDetails');
    } 
    }

    var itemInfoHover2 = {
    fetch: function (el, key, item_id) {
        showFlag = true;
        $(el).mouseout(function () {
            itemInfoHover2.hide();
        });
        clearTimeout(window.showtimeout);
        window.showtimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
            CardPopup.GetSuggestedPriceInfo(el.id, key, item_id, itemInfoHover2.show);
        }, 100);
    },

    show: function (result) {
        showVisiblePopup(suggestedPriceInfo, 'priceDetails', result.source, result.contents, false);
    },
    hide: function () {
        hideVisiblePopup('priceDetails');
    }

}
    var itemInfoHover3 = {
     fetch: function (el, key, item_id) {
        showFlag = true;
        $(el).mouseout(function () {
            itemInfoHover3.hide();
        });
        clearTimeout(window.showtimeout);
        window.showtimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
            CardPopup.GetHistoricalSalesInfo(el.id, key, item_id, window.location.pathname, itemInfoHover3.show);
        }, 100);
    },
    show: function (result) {
        showVisiblePopup(suggestedPriceInfo, 'historyDetail', result.source, result.contents, false);
    },
    hide: function () {
        hideVisiblePopup('historyDetail');
    }

}
```

Comment: The `.length` property of a function object tells you the number of formal parameters that were in its definition, if that helps.

Comment: your question is not clear to me, at all. What is the objective, and what exactly do you want to optimise?

Comment: my questions is am I able to make a function loop when there are different variables for each function inside loop?

Comment: I think `CardPopupService.thisFunction` calls the method `thisFunction` of `CardPopupService`, which is not the function you intended.

Comment: I just rewrite my question and code. Please take a look. thanks